# What is purpose of gift option in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

There is a gift option tab in back-end magento 2 with each product,what is use of that option and its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Gift Options allows you to include a gift message during checkout. Each item in the order can have a separate message. For more information, go to [this link](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-gift-options.html).